# How to force TypeORM to update an entity using repository.save() even if there are no changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have introduced certain decorators to the fields in my entity class that get triggered when an entity is saved using repository.save()

I am using entitySubscriber interface to check for events ([Reference](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/listeners-and-subscribers#what-is-a-subscriber)) and calling certain methods to perform an operation like this:

```
public beforeUpdate({ entity }: UpdateEvent<any>): void {
     encryptData(entity);
  }
```

But I noticed that this method is only called when we actually update certain fields in the entity. Is there a way to override this behaviour so that this method is called or in other words @BeforeUpdate hook is triggered every time we do a repository.save() ?

Answer (score 0):

Nope unless you modify the TypeORM sourcecode.